# 2D equivalent to 1D table for chi-squared?

Tags: chi-squared

perhaps I'm missing something - but shouldn't the following give similar results (??): (a) xxx <- t(as.matrix(c(17, 16, 47))), chisq.test(xxx), p-value = 8.829e-06 and (b) yyy <- rbind(xxx, as.integer(sum(xxx)/3)), chisq.test(yyy), p-value = 0.005852 ???? (a) is a chi-squared test of independence of the three numbers - and presumably compares with an (invisible) row of equal values - whereas (b) compares the two rows where the second row has equal values. - quite clearly the p-values are nowhere near the same (and changing the three equal values slightly doesn't help). Does anyone know why this is (?) and, more importantly, does anyone know how, or if it's possible, to write the two-dimensional table equivalent of (a) ??